# How to specify classes using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple toggle show and hide.

I have a problem though when duplicating  the classes.

My toggle works but when I duplicate the containers and press the trigger it shows all containers not just the one.

I have tried to adjust my code using the (this).find function but its not working. can someone show me where i am going wrong?

```
 <!--SHARE-->
                <a href="#share-trigger" class="share-trigger"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>Share</a>
                <div class="show-share-box">
                  <div class="share-this-wrap">
                     <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" class="share-popup share-btn" title="Share on Facebook">
                       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                       <div class="meta-share-wrap">
                         <span class="shot-social-count">4</span>
                       </div>
                     </a>

                     <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" class="share-popup share-btn" title="Share on Twitter">
                       <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                       <div class="meta-share-wrap">
                         <span class="shot-social-count">6</span>
                       </div>
                     </a>
                  </div>
                </div><!--end share box-->
```

My code that works.

```
  $(".share-trigger").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".show-share-box").slideToggle('slow');
  })
```

My code that is not working - here i have tried to add the (this function)

```
  $(".share-trigger").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).find('.show-share-box').slideToggle('slow');
  })
```

Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: We need to see a sample of your html.

Comment: show us your rendered HTML

Comment: Is `.show-share-box` element descendant of `.share-trigger` element?

Comment: Hi. I have just added my HTML

Comment: Why are people down voting. Just trying to learn !no point hating

Comment: Always post HTML whenever you are posting question related to jQuery/JavaScript. Even better provide the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). You will get answer much sooner and you won't get **downvote**

Comment: I normally do and people still down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

`$(this).next('.show-share-box').slideToggle('slow');`

Answer (score 1):

Next will select all .show-share-box so using the first in the next set should do the trick.

```
$(".share-trigger").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //$(".show-share-box").slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).next(".show-share-box").first().slideToggle('slow');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you are selecting `<a>` element as `$(this)` and finding inside `('.show-share-box')` which is sitting outside your `<a>`

you can use `.next()` or directly use `class` to toggle

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FtgN4/2/

```
$(".share-trigger").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.show-share-box').slideToggle("slow", function () {
        // animation complete
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('.show-share-box').slideToggle('slow');
```

`$(this)` --> refers to the current element which is `.share-trigger` in your case

---

`$(this).find('.show-share-box')` means find the `.show-share-box` inside `.share-trigger`

your code not working as there is no element `.show-share-box` inside `.share-trigger`

---

Updated after OP updated question.

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(this).next('.show-share-box').slideToggle('slow');
```

Comment: @patel.milanb check answer again .

Comment: how do you know that '.show-share-box' does not exits without even looking at the HTML ...

Comment: why is everyone down voting! this is just frustrating